# Issue in uploading file with custom ng-prime upload control and Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express, file-upload, primeng

I am facing this weird issue when trying to upload files using ngPrime control.

Angular template:

```
<p-fileUpload name="file" uploadLabel="Comfirm" customUpload="true" [auto]="true" maxFileSize="1000000"
                  mode="advanced"    (uploadHandler)="myUploader($event)">
```

component.ts file

```
myUploader(event) {
    this.uploadService.uploadMyFile(event);
 }
```

uploadService.ts upload method

```
private formData: FormData = new FormData();
    uploadMyFile = function(event: any) {
        console.log('My File upload', event);
        if (event.files.length == 0) {
          console.log('No file selected.');
          return;
        }

        var fileToUpload = event.files[0];
        this.formData.append('file', fileToUpload);
        console.log(this.formData);
        this.http
          .post(`<APIPath>/api/uploadfile`, this.formData, {
            headers: this.headers
          })
          .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
          });
      };
```

Request Payload

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryhiYaisgM5BgNpfkm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Cookie-song.docx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document


------WebKitFormBoundaryhiYaisgM5BgNpfkm--
```

Error in response

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token -<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse
```

NodeJS API looks like this

```
export const uploadFilesHandler = async (req, res) => {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    console.log(form);
    //upload code here
}
```

I am using bodyParser when creating NodeAPI createAPP

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '100mb' }));
```

NodeAPI console error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
    at parse (/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was coming because of the header content-Type was not set to multipart/form.

```
    @Injectable()
    export class UploadService {

        private headers= new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }); 
//^^-- Error was coming because of this was set to   
//private headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });


            uploadMyFile = function(event: any) {
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
                console.log('My File upload', event);
                if (event.files.length == 0) {
                  console.log('No file selected.');
                  return;
                }

                var fileToUpload = event.files[0];
                this.formData.append('file', fileToUpload);
                console.log(formData);
                this.http
                  .post(`<APIPath>/api/uploadfile`, formData, {
                    headers: this.headers
                  })
                  .subscribe(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                  });
              };
    }
```